# Jetpack Comments with fall-back

Tags: theme-development, comments, comment-form, plugin-jetpack

I'm developing a theme based off of [bones](http://themble.com/bones/) - I went ahead and edited the comments.php file - the comments form is hardcoded - I assumed this was the right way to do things so I carried on and structured/styled the comments form to fit in with the theme I am building.

Today I installed [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) with the aim of using their new comments system - this didn't work - after a few web searches it resulted that Jetpack [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) to work

So this is my question - How do I make use of Jetpack (therefore making use the `comment_form()` function) and keep a fall-back of my custom comment form. - I am imagining I would somehow need to place my existing comment form within a separate file/function and if Jetpack isn't present it would use it through `comment form()` - does this make any sense at all?

Any help is most appreciated.

Regards,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be interested, I think I may have found a solution - [this tutorial](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/comment-form-customization/) outlines how to customize `comment_form()`, Jetpack will simply override the styles set.